# Saving GeoPackage with style in PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, export, style, geopackage

I have a function that uses a layer already styled using another function and saves it as a `.gpkg` and I want to save the style in that `.gpkg`:

```py
def saving_gpkg(styled_layer):
    options = QgsVectorFileWriter.SaveVectorOptions()
    options.driverName = "GPKG"
    QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormatV2(styled_layer, "nice_filename", QgsCoordinateTransformContext(), options)
    styled_layer.saveStyleToDatabase("polygon", "style automatically created", True, "")
```

The `.gpkg` is created, but if I open the created file, it doesn't have the defined style, just a random single symbol. I'm missing something?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you want to save one or several layers in a geopackage, the easiest way is to use the **package** algorithm which has the `SAVE_STYLES` parameter which must be True if you want to save the styles that your layers have in the geopackage that will be generated.

```
filename = '/home/ai/Desktop/prueba.gpkg'
layers = [styled_layer]
processing.run("native:package", {'LAYERS': layers, 'OUTPUT': filename, 'OVERWRITE': False, 'SAVE_STYLES': True})
```

Answer (score 11):

A working example based on your code. Be aware that my code scope is limited as I use a layer name without space for everything whereas I should sanitized it in particular for `layername` parameter reused in the GPKG. Most of the code logic is based on [`qgsalgorithmpackage.cpp`](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/master/src/analysis/processing/qgsalgorithmpackage.cpp) C++ code used in Processing algorithm "Package layers" in the answer from @leo-cardona

```py
# Import required if not present
from qgis.PyQt.QtXml import QDomDocument
from qgis.core import (QgsReadWriteContext, QgsProject,
                       QgsVectorFileWriter, QgsVectorLayer)

def saving_gpkg(styled_layer, out_path):
    context = QgsProject.instance().transformContext()
    name = styled_layer.name()
    options = QgsVectorFileWriter.SaveVectorOptions()
    options.layerName = name
    options.fileEncoding = styled_layer.dataProvider().encoding()
    options.driverName = "GPKG"
    QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormatV2(styled_layer, out_path, context, options)
    doc = QDomDocument();
    readWriteContext = context = QgsReadWriteContext()
    styled_layer.exportNamedStyle(doc);
    gpkg_layer = QgsVectorLayer(f"{out_path}|layername={name}", name, "ogr")
    gpkg_layer.importNamedStyle(doc)
    gpkg_layer.saveStyleToDatabase(name, "", True, "")
```

Comment: I can confirm this works Using QGIS 3.16.6 :-), the only thing I needed to do was to import those extra functions: from qgis.PyQt.QtXml import QDomDocument, from qgis.core import QgsReadWriteContext and just a few renames like the input layer object and the output path. FYI my layers/datasets are in Postgres and my styles are also saved in Postgres.

Comment: Edited to add all required import

Comment: The function above only seems to save the active style. Any idea how you could adapt this for multiple styles ? I sometimes have multiple styles applied to the same layer (saved in a postgres DB).

Answer (score 2):

I developed a plugin that saves all styles with each layer as a .gpkg. Published on the official QGIS plugin repo: https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/SaveAllScript/

Comment: This is not answering the question. The Q is about programming.

Comment: I would like to clarify that this comment is relevant to the question because I created a QGIS plug-in that addresses some of the questions that the original poster had. I am sharing it here because maybe people in the future who also share the same questions can easily fix their problem with the plug-in. People are welcome to reference the code for the plug-in in order to help them with their own programming goals.

Comment: It's well documented code nonetheless - nice work @CaptainDang, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is adapted from @CaptainDang's plugin and allows for you to save each layer to the single geopackage (qgis v3.22):

Usage example:

```
  #overwrite any existing geopackages as this is the first layer I'm saving
  self.saveAs_gpkg(tmpMemory_Layer, theGeopack, True) 
        
  # Sets the layer's data source to the newly created gpkg, replaces temp layer with the permanent one
  tmpMemory_Layer.setDataSource(theGeopack + f'|layername={tmpMemory_Layer.name()}', tmpMemory_Layer.name(), 'ogr')
```

requirements:

```
from qgis import processing
```

code:

```
def saveAs_gpkg(self, styled_layer, theFileandPath, OptionsOverwriteFile):
    #output_file = os.path.join(new_folder_path, layer_name + ".gpkg")
    #if not os.path.exists(theFileandPath):
    parameters = {
        'LAYERS': [styled_layer],
        'OUTPUT': theFileandPath + ".gpkg",
        # Specify the output file with .gpkg extension
        'OVERWRITE': OptionsOverwriteFile,
        'SAVE_STYLES': True,
        'SAVE_METADATA': True,
        'SELECTED_FEATURES_ONLY': False,
        'EXPORT_RELATED_LAYERS': False}

    feedback = QgsProcessingFeedback()

    # Execute the package algorithm
    try:
        result = processing.run("native:package", parameters, feedback=feedback)
        if result['OUTPUT']:
            pass
        else:
            iface.messageBar().pushMessage("Failed: ",
                                           "layer '{}' was not saved.".format(
                                               styled_layer.name()), level=2)
            failedSaves.append(layer_name)
    except QgsProcessingException as e:
        iface.messageBar().pushMessage("Error: ",
                                       "An error occurred while packaging layer '{}': '{}'".format(
                                           styled_layer.name(), str(e)), level=2)
```